# css transform - gaps (white points) between two shapes

Tags: css, transform, space, skew

I connect multiple skewed divs, so that a ring arise.
But between the different divs there are white pixels. The gaps depend on the zoom-level.
How can I fix this?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="o4iApp">

  <head>
    <title>Kompetenzatlas</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.10.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-resource@*" data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div ng-view=""></div>

  </body>

</html>
```

You can see how it works at http://plnkr.co/edit/uv6W2CpqXdY8jMJTDKKf?p=preview

In Firefox the problem becomes very clear. There are white lines between the segments.

Comment: Please add a link to your site and the code in which you're having a problem.

Comment: I post a plunker with my code in **EDIT 1**